# Move notifications to smaller display on the right side

Tags: display, high-sierra, notifications

OS:  High Sierra

I have dual displays and want notifications in the upper-right corner of my smaller secondary display, which is to the right of my larger primary.  Initially, in System Settings, I moved the menu bar to the smaller display on the right, which achieves my desired notification location.

[image]

However, this also results in undesirable side effects, such as my volume and eject overlays showing on the smaller "secondary" monitor as one example.

Is there a way to force notifications to appear on the smaller display without moving the menu bar to this location?

Comment: @Tetsujin, no kidding - I already know that.  Is there any other way to move the notifications to the secondary display?

Comment: @Tetsujin, "primary" and "secondary" are not official Apple terms based on written descriptions in System Settings.  So I thought the picture and the physical description of my setup was clear enough: *"my **smaller** secondary display, **which is to the right** of my larger primary"*.  If there is absolutely no solution or workaround to *"force notifications to appear on the smaller monitor without moving the menu bar"*, then please post that as the answer instead of ignoring common SE etiquette by playing around with the semantics.

Comment: @Tetsujin, and so do you, so let's start over.  I edited the OP to clarify more.  Is there a solution or workaround?  Even if not, that would make an acceptable answer.